# Intent immediately defaults to FallbackIntent, even with incredibly specific utterance

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

[the utterance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUnnA.png)
[the slot being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw0G0.png)

[the testing screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9U9w.png)

the intent in my lambda function:

```
var phoneNumber;    
"getPhoneNumberIntent": function() {
    phoneNumber = this.event.request.intent.slots.phoneNumber.value;
    if (getLength(phoneNumber) === 10) {
        this.response.speak('I heard <say-as interpret-as="telephone"> ' + phoneNumber + '</say-as>. Is this the correct number?').listen();
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    } else {
        console.log(phoneNumber);
        this.response.speak('That is not a valid phone number. Please try again.').listen();

    }
},
```

When I type in the incredibly specific utterance, The only thing in the output JSON is null. and in the input, the proper intent wasn't even being called. I have not seen a problem similar to mine on the website, I've looked high and low. Any help or feedback is appreciated.

Comment: What is the intent name that the slot phone number is corresponding to, and is fallback intent handler listed as the very last intent handler to be tried in your code base. It should be because it will always be true so the handler you are trying to hit should report true prior to fallback.

Comment: Lastly, in the testing console enter the number one, one, one, one, one, one, one, one, one, one not 1111111111 it is not interpreting the ints as spoken numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use predefined `AMAZON.NUMBER` as the slot type for `phoneNumber`.

While testing numbers in Alexa Test Simulator, represent them as words

> Ex: the phone number is nine eight seven six five four three two one
>   zero

And for abbreviations use period "."

> Ex: The code is a.w.e.